# how to add up element in multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, sum

I feel like the answer so simple but I just can't figure out what it is. I have an multidimensional array such as this:

```
    int [][] number = 
    {{ 10, 15, 11, 13, 72, 87, 266},
        { 50, 65, 80, 94, 12, 134, 248}, 
        { 1, 2, 1, 9, 1, 39, 26}, 
        { 13, 20, 76, 4, 8, 72, 28}, 
        { 2, 1, 29, 2, 12, 907, 92}, 
        { 16, 4, 308, 7, 127, 1, 52}
    };
```

I'm trying to add up all the integers in the each array index and display it at the end so what I thought up of is this

```
int total=0;
    for (int k=0;k<6;k++){
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++){

    total=number[k][i]+total;}}
    System.out.println(total);
```

What I noticed is that it will add up all the numbers in the entire array. But how do I stop it at the end of each index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't the loop be like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    total += number[k][i];
  }
  System.out.println(total);
}
```

Assuming I get what you mean by *stop it at the end of each index*.

And better should it be if you parametrize your loops to fit in each dimension length:

```
for (int k = 0; k < number.length; k++) {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < number[k].length; i++) {
    total += number[k][i];
  }
  System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry for not explaining myself correctly

Comment: So since I got it right, I suppose the answer solves your problem so you can accept it and even upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear . But from what I understood you must do

```
for (int k=0;k<6;k++){
   int total=0;
   for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
      total=number[k][i]+total;}
   System.out.println(total);}
```

It will print sum of all rows